# ui-grid won't render data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to display the data in the table that I am accessing from rest API. My code to implement it is as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="AuditorReportController as vm">

    <div ui-grid="vm.gridOptions" style="padding-top: 10%;">
    </div>

</div>
```

controller:

```
var vm = this;
        var i;
        // activate();
        var dataitems;
        vm.gridOptions = {};
        var gridData;

function userEventData (resp) {
            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: resp.results["@href"]
            }).success(function (responseData) {
                logger.info("userEventData responseData", responseData);
                vm.gridOptions.data = responseData;
                logger.info("gridOptions", vm.gridOptions.data);
                filterEventField(responseData);
                //return responseData;
            });
        }

function populateGrid (responseData) {
            logger.info("populateGrid function activated");
            vm.dateFormat = "medium";
            vm.gridOptions = {
                enableColumnMenus: false,
                enableColumnResizing: true,
                enableHorizontalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.WHEN_NEEDED,
                enableVerticalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
                enableRowSelection: true,
                enableSelectAll: true,
                paginationPageSizes: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50], // Using the same options as old UI
                paginationPageSize: 20, // Use 20 as the default page size everywhere until user changes it
                paginationTemplate: "core/templates/ui-grid-pagination-template.html",
                rowTemplate: gridService.getRowTemplate(),
                useExternalPagination: true,
                useExternalSorting: true,
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        field: "sun",
                        displayName: "Init User",
                        enableHiding: false,
                        allowCellFocus: false
                    },
                    {
                        field: "dun",
                        displayName: "Target User",
                        enableHiding: false,
                        allowCellFocus: false
                    },
                    {
                        field: "evt",
                        displayName: "Name",
                        enableHiding: false,
                        allowCellFocus: false
                    },
                    {
                        field: "dip",
                        displayName: "What is affected",
                        enableHiding: false,
                        allowCellFocus: false
                    },
                    {
                        field: "det",
                        displayName: "Time created",
                        enableHiding: false,
                        allowCellFocus: false
                    }
                ],
                /**
                 * @ngdoc function
                 * @name gridApi
                 * @memberof app.alerts.grid.AlertViewsController.populateGrid
                 * @summary
                 * ui grid call back functions
                 */
                onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                    vm.gridApi = gridApi;
                }

            }
                vm.gridOptions.totalItems = vm.totalCount;
        }
```

With this code, all I am getting is an empty table with column fields. No data is being displayed. The data being returned from the API is in the following format:

```
{
  "next": {
    "@href": "https://objects/event?page=2&pagesize=25&field=evt&field=det&field=spt&field=dip&field=dun&field=sun&query=_jobid_.efa2ebf67d479e39d49385D60384E1035B880000C29194FA7"
  },
  "objects": [
    {
      "meta": {
        "type": "event",
        "@href": "https://objects/event/1498008581468/49385D60-384E-1035-B44E-000C29194FA7"
      },
      "det": "2017-06-21T01:29:41.468Z",
      "dip": "12.16.12.18",
      "spt": "2017-06-21T01:29:41.468Z",
      "evt": "LoginUser",
      "dun": "admin",
      "sun": "admin"
    },
    {
      "meta": {
        "type": "event",
        "@href": "https://objects/event/1498008581439/49385D60-384E-1035-B44C-000C29194FA7"
      },
      "det": "2017-06-21T01:29:41.439Z",
      "dip": "12.16.12.18",
      "spt": "2017-06-21T01:29:41.439Z",
      "evt": "IssueSAMLToken",
      "dun": "admin",
      "sun": "admin"
    },
    {
      "meta": {
        "type": "event",
        "@href": "https:/1DEF74E0-376D-1035-AF66-000C29194FA7"
      },
      "det": "2017-06-20T02:16:55.799Z",
      "dip": "12.16.12.18",
      "spt": "2017-06-20T02:16:55.799Z",
      "evt": "LogOffUser",
      "dun": "admin",
      "sun": "admin"
    }
  ]
}
```

Do I need to format the data such that it is readable by vm.gridOptions.data?
Currently, all i am getting is :
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the response is returning an array ? 
vm.gridOptions.data = responseData;
The response is pushed into the variable above but are you trying to iterate the same variable in the HTML ?

Comment: Yea i am iterating over responseData.objects.length.
for (i = 0; i < responseData.objects.length; i++) {
                tempData = responseData.objects[i];
            }
            vm.gridOptions.data = tempData;
Am I in the right direction?

Comment: I didnt see that piece of code in your post. If the server response is an array, then you will have to iterate angular.forEach(response.data, function(element, index) { vm.gridOptions.push(element) }. Then you can use vm.gridOptions in your html to iterate. Also you should declare vm.gridOptions as array [] and not as object {}

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was define vm.gridOptions in populateGrid() function where i define the vm.gridOptions object.
I created a temp object where I store responseData and then assign it to vm.gridOptions.data

```
function populateGrid () {
            vm.dateFormat = "medium";
            var temp = vm.gridOptions.data;
            vm.gridOptions = {
                enableColumnMenus: false,
                enableColumnResizing: true,
                enableHorizontalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.WHEN_NEEDED,
                enableVerticalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
                enableRowSelection: true,
                enableSelectAll: true,
                paginationPageSizes: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50], // Using the same options as old UI
                paginationPageSize: 20, // Use 20 as the default page size everywhere until user changes it
                paginationTemplate: "core/templates/ui-grid-pagination-template.html",
                rowTemplate: gridService.getRowTemplate(),
                useExternalPagination: true,
                useExternalSorting: true,
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        field: "sun",
                        displayName: "Init User",
                        enableHiding: false,
                        allowCellFocus: false
                    },
                    {
                        field: "dun",
                        displayName: "Target User",
                        enableHiding: false,
                        allowCellFocus: false
                    },
                    {
                        field: "evt",
                        displayName: "Name",
                        enableHiding: false,
                        allowCellFocus: false
                    },
                    {
                        field: "dip",
                        displayName: "What is affected",
                        enableHiding: false,
                        allowCellFocus: false
                    },
                    {
                        field: "det",
                        displayName: "Time created",
                        enableHiding: false,
                        allowCellFocus: false
                    }
                ],
                /**
                 * @ngdoc function
                 * @name gridApi
                 * @memberof app.alerts.grid.AlertViewsController.populateGrid
                 * @summary
                 * ui grid call back functions
                 */
                onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                    vm.gridApi = gridApi;
                }

            }
                vm.gridOptions.totalItems = vm.totalCount;
                vm.gridOptions.data = temp.objects;
        }
```